# Возможность написать сообщение с помощью vk апи

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, вконтакте

Есть задача: сделать метод, который отправляет сообщение в ЛС. Но после 2019, ВК закрыли апи сообщений. Есть способ обойти это ограничение?
UPD1: есть статья на хабре, я не совсем понял сути, но может это поможет?
https://habr.com/ru/post/446172/

Comment: Можно создать группу, затем создать api ключ в настройках, и писать сообщения от имени сообщества. Но только тем пользователям, которые дали доступ на это(хотя бы один раз написали в ваше сообщество), если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужен код, который отправляет сообщения через ТВОЙ аккаунт, а не сообщество.

Answer (score 1):

```
import vk_api

def write_msg(user_id, message):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id,
                                        'message': message,
                                        'random_id': get_random_id()})

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="000000000")

write_msg(1, "Hello world")
```

1 аргумент - id странички вк

2 аргумент - сообщение

Comment: Если ввести этот код, то выскакивает ошибка за random_id. Если его убрать, выходит ошибка о том, что недостаточно прав на совершение данного действия. P.S. я почитал, что такое random_id и попробовал его вернуть в виде нуля. Выходит тоже самое, что и если его убрать. vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: no access to call this method Вот код ошибки

Comment: @АнтонТроянов, из либы импортнуть надо функцию, которая генерит рандом id. Но подозреваю, что вы задумали что-то невозможное.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы правы. С импортом я разобрался, спасибо, буду знать. А вот ошибка доступа никуда не делась.